# How do you sort a mongo database by the nth item in an array using node js?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, sorting

For example the database looks like this

```
{
  id: 1,
  counter: [2,6]
},
{
  id: 2,
  counter: [5,10]
},
{
  id: 3,
  counter: [1,3]
}
```

Now I want to sort it by for example the second item in each array so the result comes out like this

```
{
  id: 2,
  counter: [5,10]
},
{
  id: 1,
  counter: [2,6]
},
{
  id: 3,
  counter: [1,3]
}
```

Anyone know how this could be pulled off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Pipeline:

- `$addFields` to add new field `sorter` which will be equal to second item of the array
- `$sort` to sort the result based on new field
- `$project` to specify which properties to return from the result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sorter": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$counter",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "sorter": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sorter": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tnOL44TNlAI

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort property

```js
const data = [{
  id: 2,
  counter: [5,10]
},
{
  id: 1,
  counter: [2,6]
},
{
  id: 3,
  counter: [1,3]
}]

data.sort((a, b)=>{
  return a.counter[1] > b.counter[1]
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I have 20,000 documents in this database so that wouldn't be very efficient good idea though!